# How to filter list on the dropdown according to the word we typed in the textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have one dropdown and one Textbox, where the data in the dropdown is very much.so I want to make a filter function on the textbox, where when we fill in the word in Textbox and after pressing the filter button then the one that appears in the dropdown is only the word corresponding to Textbox.
below is my code

Controller

```
public ActionResult GetInsuranceCompany(string code)
{
   string codeJP = string.Empty;
   ParamJenisPembayaran paramJP = db.ParamJenisPembayarans.Where(x => x.Code == code).FirstOrDefault();
   if (paramJP != null) codeJP = paramJP.Name;

   var states = db.InsuranceCompany_CSFs.Where(x => x.JenisPembayaran == codeJP).ToList();
   List<SelectListItem> listates = new List<SelectListItem>();
   listates.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select InsuranceCompany--", Value = "0" }); 
    if (states != null){
          foreach (var x in states){
             listates.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.CompanyName, Value = x.CompanyName});
          }
    }
    return Json(new SelectList(listates, "Value", "Text", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
}

 [HttpPost]
 [MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "SearchFilterThirdParty")]
 public ActionResult SearchFilterThirdParty(ParamBlacklistPembayaranViewModel model)
 {
    //code
 }
```

View

```
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SearchFilterThirdParty, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } }) //textbox to filter the dropdown below
  <input type="submit" value="Filter" name="action:SearchFilterThirdParty" /> 
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AddNewThirdParty, ViewBag.country as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

View Model

```
public class ParamBlacklistPembayaranViewModel
{
     public string SearchFilterThirdParty { get; set; }
     public string AddNewThirdParty { get; set; }
}
```

*public ActionResult GetInsuranceCompany* is to call all data in the other dropdown according to the previously selected list (Cascading DropDownList) I made it use ajax and this has worked. I do not include other dropdowns in the code above. 
I know the *public Action Result SearchFilterThirdParty* is still empty, there I want to make a function for the filter but I don't know how. Any idea? thanks.

Comment: Can you not use a text box associated with a `<datalist>` instead of a `<select>` in the resulting HTML? (This effectively turns your text box into a combo box, with the listed items being filtered by the typed text.)

Comment: Do you mean I am changing  `<SelectListItem>` to `<datalist>` in  HTML? @AgiHammerthief

Comment: Yes, exactly that. So your HTML ends up looking something like this, IDs substituted as appropriate: `<input type="text" list="filterDL" id="id" /><datalist id="filterDL" name="filterDL"><!-- items here are what's currently in your SelectList --></datalist>` [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) for reference